# MYSQL Dump Formatted Text File

Tags: mysql

I have a service which produce formatted text files with information from certain tables in a MYSQL db.
Currently I programmatically query the DB and dump it in a TEXT file. 
I wonder if i can do the same from within the MYSQL db.

This means that when a new record is added to a specific table, MYSQL will run a piece of code that will generate that formatted text file.

Comment: You could [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html) from a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html).

Comment: @eggyal Not sure, but problem might be that the file gets overwritten rather than new entries appended? So you have to write the whole table every time you insert a record.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell much about your use cases, but maybe the CSV engine might be what you're looking for?

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/csv-storage-engine.html):

When you create a CSV table, the server creates a table format file in the database directory. The file begins with the table name and has an .frm extension. The storage engine also creates a data file. Its name begins with the table name and has a .CSV extension. The data file is a plain text file. When you store data into the table, the storage engine saves it into the data file in comma-separated values format.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test (i INT NOT NULL, c CHAR(10) NOT NULL)
    -> ENGINE = CSV;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,'record one'),(2,'record two');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+------+------------+
| i    | c          |
+------+------------+
|    1 | record one |
|    2 | record two |
+------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Starting with MySQL 5.1.9, creating a CSV table also creates a corresponding Metafile that stores the state of the table and the number of rows that exist in the table. The name of this file is the same as the name of the table with the extension CSM.

If you examine the test.CSV file in the database directory created by executing the preceding statements, its contents should look like this:

```
"1","record one"
"2","record two"
```

**This format can be read, and even written, by spreadsheet applications such as Microsoft Excel or StarOffice Calc.**